# MVVM Should I Move View Logic to ViewModel?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-mvvm

For MVVM, I understand that the general consensus is to make the view as "dumb" as possible. In the context of Android, would it be incorrect to do any type of display logic in the View(Fragment)? In the example below, I'm displaying different text according to countValue. Does this violate the pattern? Should I hoist this logic to the ViewModel and create another LiveData object for setting the correct countValueMessage?

For example,

```
        mBinding.countValue.setText(String.valueOf(countValue));
        if (countValue > 0) {
            mBinding.countValueMessage.setText("Count greater than 0");
        } else {
            mBinding.countValueMessage.setText("Count less than 0");
        }
```

Comment: *make the view as "dumb" as possible* that is not right - the view should only do view/presentation logic - period. That can be very complicated and the opposite of being dumb. In your example the viewmodel only has to provide the countValue to the view and the view will choose the right text for presenting that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the context of Android, would it be incorrect to do any type of display logic in the View(Fragment)?

This is bordering on opinion - I've seen dozens of projects that claim to do "MVVM" that look completely differently, but none is "wrong", per se.

But for your example, I'd say that is logic that belongs in the ViewModel.

- Job of the View: display currently observed state and delegate UI events.
- Job of the ViewModel: Process events / business logic to determine *what* to display and update the current view state to match.

> In the example below, I'm displaying different text according to countValue. Does this violate the pattern?

I'd say so.

> Should I hoist this logic to the ViewModel and create another LiveData object for setting the correct countValueMessage?

I'd say so, but you don't necessarily have to create another LiveData object. Having a LiveData for every single piece of UI state gets old *fast*. Instead, you can have *one* object that represents the current view state, [as shown in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer#define-ui-state).

Then your view is oh so dumb:

```
mViewModel.uiStateLiveData.observe(this) {
    // I stoopid - I set values as I am told - I no think
    mBinding.countValue.setText(it.countValueText);
    mBinding.otherThing.setText(it.otherThingText);
    mBinding.thirdThing.setVisibility(it.thirdThingVisibility);
    // ETC ETC
}
```

Note that sometimes you don't want to update the *entire* view when *one* thing changes, so then you can break those out into multiple livedata as needed.

All the "logic" of checking `countValue` and what string to show and whether this or that is visible is in the ViewModel, completely independent of Android and the View and completely unit-testable.

You can write UI tests that are simple and straightforward that just say "given this view state, assert the views are as expected".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. As you mentioned, it sounds like a good idea to group these into one object. Sir Rufo made a comment under my question. Based on your response, would you say that you agree with what he says? Similar to you, I'd prefer to put that logic in the ViewModel.

Comment: @dman224 In your example you want to present the value from `countValue`. The view has everything and more information how to present this. 1. In which language should that message appear? The view knows it 2. At what place should that message appear? Do we need a long text or a shorter one or just the simple value? The view knows it. Because of this 2 points, why on earth should I move this logic to the viewmodel, when it can be easily and much better solved by the view itself?

Comment: @SirRufo What would you say is the purpose of the ViewModel layer then? If the purpose of the ViewModel is just to pass the value to the fragment (View), then I don't really see a point in having a ViewModel.

Comment: @dman224 If there is only one property in the VM and no other logic involved, then it would agree, but my VMs are slightly more complex, talking to providers and services to get the values it will pass to the view for presentation.

Comment: @SirRufo Why would you not do that logic in the Repository layer? Shouldn't that be where you interact with your APIs and local database?

Comment: @dman224 To answer your first question, I do not agree, but again, this is matter of opinion. "view logic", IMO, is something like managing an animation, doing custom drawing, etc. Determining what text to show based on some value, IMO, is _business_ logic that determines the final state of the view and has no place in the view itself.